# Assigning zero to tensor at indices specified in a list

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to tensors, for example

```
A = tf.Tensor(
       [[1.0986123 0.6931472 0.        0.6931472 0.       ]
        [0.        0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
        [3.7376697 3.7612002 3.7841897 3.8066626 3.8286414]], shape=(3, 5), dtype=float32)

B = tf.Tensor(
   [[2 1]
    [2 2]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int64)
```

Tensor `B` holds indices in tensor `A`. I want to update every value in tensor `A` to zero that is listed in the index list `B`.

So, the expected result would be

```
tf.Tensor(
       [[1.0986123 0.6931472 0.        0.6931472 0.       ]
        [0.        0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
        [3.7376697 0 0 3.8066626 3.8286414]], shape=(3, 5), dtype=float32)
```

So the entries at index [2,1] and [2, 2] are set to 0.

I looked at `tf.assign` but they can only be used for `tf.Variable`'s. `tf.boolean_mask` would be a nice way to do it, but i do not know and could not find out how i can create a boolean mask with a list of indices.

I looked at the tensor flow functions i could find and related S/O answers but couldn't find a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.scatter_nd_update` for this. For example:

```
A = tf.Variable(
    [[1.0986123, 0.6931472, 0.       , 0.6931472, 0.       ],
     [0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ],
     [3.7376697, 3.7612002, 3.7841897, 3.8066626, 3.8286414]], dtype=tf.float32)

B = tf.Variable(
    [[2, 1],
     [2, 2]], dtype=tf.int64)

C = tf.scatter_nd_update(A, B, tf.zeros(shape=tf.shape(B)[0]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(C))
```

or

```
A = tf.constant(
    [[1.0986123, 0.6931472, 0.       , 0.6931472, 0.       ],
     [0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ],
     [3.7376697, 3.7612002, 3.7841897, 3.8066626, 3.8286414]], dtype=tf.float32)

B = tf.constant(
    [[2, 1],
     [2, 2]], dtype=tf.int64)

AV = tf.Variable(A)

C = tf.scatter_nd_update(AV, B, tf.zeros(shape=tf.shape(B)[0]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(C))
```

Comment: Thanks! My tensors come from the Dataset api so they are not `tf.Variable`'s. I figured i can create a variable from the incoming tensor, apply `scatter_nd_update` and then convert it into a tensor again. Hacky but it works: `tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.scatter_nd_update(tf.contrib.eager.Variable(input_data),
                                                     index_list,
                                                     tf.zeros(shape=tf.shape(index_list)[0])))`

Comment: i would like to continue research if there is a solution without using variables, maybe with `tf.boolean_mask` and if i don't find something i can accept your answer

Comment: I add code with constant instead variable. This is same behavior as tf.Tensor